# Chrome extension to save currently loaded HTML (not the originally loaded one)

Tags: html, chrome

Chrome's default "save page as HTML" (even with "Webpage complete") option saves the **original HTML**.

This fails on sites render the whole HTML through Javascript, or modify HTML after some time/actions. I want to save this **modified HTML**, and not the the one that was originally loaded.

I can do this manually in Developer Tools > Elements tab > right click the `<html>` tag and then Copy outerHTML

Is there an extension that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Save Page WE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof)
- <strike>[SingleFile](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle?hl=en)</strike> (no longer working for me)